# Trouble flushing output stream on iOS

Tags: ios, json, sockets, outputstream, flush

I am a newbie in client server programming so please pardon me if I have made some obvious errors.

To give a context, we are working on a client server application where client is sending images/vidoes in json to the server over socket.

Also we are sending single image/video file in muliple packet - where packet size is 2kb

Here is my code

```
-(void)sendDataToServer:(NSData*)tmpdata

{
    NSMutableData *jsonData = [tmpdata mutableCopy];
    NSData *nsdata = [@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [jsonData appendData:nsdata];
    uint32_t some_long = (uint32_t)[jsonData length];
    uint32_t network_byte_order;
    //convert and send
    network_byte_order = htonl(some_long);
    NSUInteger len = [jsonData length];
    int litIndianSize;
    [[NSData dataWithBytes:&len length:4] getBytes:&litIndianSize length: sizeof(litIndianSize)];
    NSLog(@"actaul data of 4 byte=%i",litIndianSize);
    NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithBytes: &network_byte_order length:sizeof(network_byte_order)];
    NSMutableData *completeData = [data2 mutableCopy];
    [completeData appendData:jsonData];

    if([outputStream write:[completeData bytes] maxLength:[completeData length]]==-1)
    {
        NSLog(@"error in writing on stream");
    }
}
```

But this code is giving "Parsing Error" on server. Below is what I believe is happening.

Since client is sending these packets to server very fast, sometimes the output stream is not flushed properly. This causes multiple packets to get combined in one packet which server is not able to parse as one json packet.

Can you please tell me if there is something wrong with my code or if there is any other way to flush output stream properly?

Also, Android clients are able to send images/video to server successfully using same principles (packet size as 2 KB etc). (If needed, I can have Android code posted here too)

Comment: On the server, how do you distinguish each coming packet? (so that you can parse it properly)

Comment: @user523234,  While sending the packet I add actual message length in first 4 bytes of the packet.

On server - while parsing it looks for first 4 bytes to identify the actual message length.

We are using Netty framework to handle the incoming packets on server.

Comment: This NSUInteger is a 8 bytes length not 4.  Do this: NSLog(@"size of NSUInteger: %lu", sizeof(NSUInteger));

Comment: Thanx for reply!I have also tried to store lenth with int (4 byte) at the place of NSInteger to store size

Comment: @user523234
  I have also printed the Size as mentioned by you " NSLog(@"size of NSUInteger: %lu", sizeof(NSUInteger));" It return's "size of NSUInteger: 4"